# Guardar parametros de una funcion

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

Buen día, mi consulta es simple tengo esta función:

```
capturaInformacion(estadoId:number, nombreEstado:string){
    let data = {
            "estadoId": estadoId,
            "nombreEstado": nombreEstado
    }
    // mostrar el estado y el nombre de la informacion
    console.log("Estado + Nombre del Id", data);
}
```

Necesito guardar los parametros en una variable, he intentado de esta manera:

```
// Nombre de mi Variable   // Nombre de la Funcion y sus Parametros  
this.informationCapture =  this.capturaInformacion(estadoId, data.nombreEstado);
```

Pero no he logrado nada con eso y mi idea es utilizar la variable para mostrar **nombreEstado** utlizando la interpolación en Angular.

Comment: Que te trae `this.informationCapture`?

Comment: Seguramente se quede como `undefined` porque el método no devuelve nada

Comment: @Cris223511.dev es una variable ya declara solo que esta vacia por que ahi es donde quiero guardar los parametros de mi función.

Comment: @PabloLozano en este caso que me corresponderia hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función no devuelve nada, por lo que el código ejecutado no tiene ninguna consecuencia. Deberías hacer algo como:

```js
capturaInformacion(estadoId:number, nombreEstado:string){
  return {
    estadoId,
    nombreEstado
  };
}
```

De ese modo, la propiedad informationCapture pasará a tener el valor devuelto.